# Understanding formula for comparing players based on certain metrics

Tags: similarities

I'm looking at this tool: https://www.capfriendly.com/comparables/ and trying to understand the formula behind its rankings. I don't really need the exact formula, I really just need a way to compare multiple players to one specific player, and somehow end up with a "% match".

The tool allows you to enter a players name and it will show you a list of players that are "similar" to that player. And it allows you to adjust your definition of "similar" as well using sliders in the "Component Importance" section.

So if I enter player "Jack Eichel"

[image]

It will give me a list of "similar" players.

[image]

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to take all these attributes into account and end up with a "% match". Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: so you need a similarity measure to compare players, and you don't need the exact one used by that tool. You can compute your own similarity measure if you want, choosing among the most popular ones. Check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure

Comment: The possibilities are endless.  For the formula used by that site, consider contacting the site developers or--if they have it--consulting their documentation.